# Question about SVD and orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, orthogonal-matrices

Let $X$ be a $m \times n$ matrix. By SVD, I obtain $X = UDV^T$, where $U$ and $V$ are both orthogonal matrices, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

I think the following is true (but not sure why):

$(VDV^T + aI_n)^{-1} = V(D + aI_n)^{-1}V^T$

where $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is some scalar, and $I_n$ is a $n\times n$ identity matrix. Can anyone explain to me why one is able to move $V$ to the left of the matrix inverse and $V^T$ to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the SVD has to do with it but yes, your manipulation is correct.

We are given that $D$ is diagonal and $V$ is orthogonal. Note that $V^{-1} = V^T$ and $(V^T)^{-1} = V$. So, we have
$$
\begin{align}
(VDV^T + aI_n)^{-1} 
&= (VDV^T + V(a I_n)V^T)^{-1} 
\\ & = (V(D + aI_n)V^T)^{-1}
\\ & = (V^T)^{-1}(D + aI_n)^{-1}V^{-1} 
= V(D + aI_n)^{-1}V^T.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks, and it should be $(D + aI_n)^{-1}$ instead of $(D + aI_n)$ in the last line right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is invertible,

$$(VMV^{-1}+aI)^{-1}=(VMV^{-1}+aVV^{-1})^{-1}=(V(M+aI)V^{-1})^{-1}=V(M+aI)^{-1}V^{-1}.$$

If, in addition, $V$ is orthogonal, this is

$$V(M+aI)^{-1}V^T.$$

Nothing else is required.